# In android logcat some of the log information missing .How to see all log cat details/data or save in a file?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

Im new to android.

Im developing some android app.

It sends/receive the data to/from server

I shows the the data from server which is received in log cat.

The data is received the application processed it.

But in log cat

the following is displayed

```
?:??: W/?(?): --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
08-01 10:55:33.676: I/KeyInputQueue(176): Enqueueing touch event0
08-01 10:55:33.676: I/WindowManager(176): Read next event 0
08-01 10:55:33.676: I/WindowManager(176): Delivering pointer 0 > Window{4a7c2ad0 InputMethod paused=false}
08-01 10:55:33.823: I/KeyInputQueue(176): Enqueueing touch event1
08-01 10:55:33.833: I/WindowManager(176): Read next event 1
08-01 10:55:33.833: I/WindowManager(176): Delivering pointer 1 > Window{4a7c2ad0 InputMethod paused=false}
08-01 10:55:34.053: D/BatteryService(176): update start
08-01 10:55:34.053: D/BatteryService(176): update start
08-01 10:55:34.053: D/BatteryService(176): update st
```

The data in logcat before the first line  "    ?:??: W/?(?): --------- beginning of /dev/log/system" is not come logcat or some data eliminated in logcat.

I does not know why it happens .Some of the logcat data /lines is deleted .I cannot figure out

Please give your ideas how to get the complete logcat data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the solution.

In eclipse for android there is buffer for logcat.That is accessed/edited by the folowing process.

Select the following menu in eclipse: Windows->Preferences then select "Android" from list in left tab. Then expand the "Android" tab then select the "LogCat" then see/edit the text field ("Maximum number of logcat messages to buffer").

If the logcat message is larger than the buffer size then the eclipse shows only the some portion of data/log cat.

So i write the messages which i already put in logcat is written in the text file.

Comment: Just make sure Eclipse (or the IDE your using) has access to enough memory to show these messages.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your DDMS then below the DDMS icon there is one icon move your cursor over there it will display hint like "Display saved filter view" click on that you will find other tab opened at right side for that tab select "All messages(no filters)"

Answer (score 0):

SIVAKUMAR some times if there is a large set of values eclipse might not show those all , so you need to restart the eclipse in that case .
Start the application again you will see all the values .
If you want to save the logcat file select all values of logcat and the first button ,
(Export selected items to TextFIle )in logcat shall give you the option to save the selected part of logcat as a file.

Answer (score -1):

Plz try to explain ur question correctly.

As I have understood, u just need to drag from right most side. Also u can select Filter options fro leftmost box.

For more information refer [this](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html).